# image not displaying in ajax call in plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on plugin where from one page I have ajax call, depending on it should get result from the other page ie. `submit.php` which is in plugin directory. The `submit.php` has no code apart from image tags. I have tried many wp function like `bloginfo('template_url')` and other. But none of them is working. What should I do to make these function work in `submit.php` to display image because in `submit.php` there is other wordpress function?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var nm = $("#nm").val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"submit.php",
            type:"post",
            data : "nm="+nm
        }).done(function(obj){
            $("#pre").html(obj);

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: share code from submit.php also

Comment: in submit.php i want to load image from wordpress folder,but wp does not recognizes this page . so any wp function that i used to get image path is not working . in submit.php there is only image tag

Comment: Did you included _wp-config.php_ in _submit.php_ in order to have access to WP functions?